# PHP switch issue

Tags: php

Is this method right?

```
switch ($_GET['get']){ 
  case 'show':
        echo 'show';
  break;

  case is_numeric($_GET['app']):
        echo $_GET['app'];
  break;
}
```

Comment: Have you run it? To me it doesn't look like it would work, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not able to tell whether this is syntactically valid but it makes no sense:

```
case is_numeric($_GET['app']):
```

You're comparing `$_GET['get']` with the (Boolean) result of `is_numeric()`. This *may* be what you intend but I doubt it. <del>Furthermore, I'm not sure if you can have expressions (i.e., non-simple language constructs) after the `case` keyword.</del> (Seems to be valid, cf. my edit.)

---

**EDIT**
Based on the [comments in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) it's possibly valid. And due to the loose comparison used by `switch` the above *may* actually reflect your intention. If this is the case, please ignore my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The code is valid.

Comment: I have NEVER seen anyone use a function after a case statement...this is a good example why people think bad things about PHP. You should try this in C#

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be the sarcastic old man in the corner and say I honestly don't know why anyone uses switch statements in PHP. Really. They are so horrible.

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
if ($_GET['get'] == "show") {
echo "show";
} else if (is_numeric($_GET['app'])) {
echo $_GET['app'];
}
```

That's so much simpler to understand!

The one reply to my question is to avoid calculating the same thing twice. For example, this is bad:

```
if (BigSlowFunctionCall() == 1) { 
... 
} else if (BigSlowFunctionCall() == 2) {
...
}
```

If it's 2, then you've just called BigSlowFunctionCall() twice - not efficient. But here's how you get round that:

```
$resultOfBigSlowFunctionCall = BigSlowFunctionCall();
if ($resultOfBigSlowFunctionCall == 1) { 
... 
} else if ($resultOfBigSlowFunctionCall == 2) {
...
}
```

I argue that's still much more readable than a switch statement.

Sorry. I'm not having a good day.

Comment: And Yes, I do know coding style is a matter of personal preference .... Sorry. Hopefully I'll cheer up soon.

Comment: Dude i really really love switch statements, Where does continue apply in a if statement? I think dismissing switch because someone misuses its purpose is just plain wrong.

Comment: @stephen I've just looked up the code examples on http://uk.php.net/continue and I'm still sticking to my original point of "Is that what you call readable?" Maybe there are purposes a switch statment can be used for, every time I've seen one I just think it could be replaced with an if else block and be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using something like this: (i would personally fetch the whole $_GET array and use a foreach loop, but there you go)

```
 function parseGet($getVar)
    {  
       if(is_numeric($getVar)) echo $getVar;
       else
       {
         switch($getVar)
         {
            case "show":
                echo "show";
            break;
         }       
       }        
    }

parseGet($_GET['show']);
```

Comment: What's the switch statement doing in there that a else if wouldn't?